# How change the directory where files are saved in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet in a Codeigniter project. By default PHPSpreadsheet excel files are downloaded to the download directory . I want to change the save directory in PhpSpreadsheet to `C://xampp/htdocs` because I want to send an email with the saved file. Is this possible in PhpSpreadsheet?

Comment: Are you talking about downloaded files created by PHPSpreadsheet or files being saved on the server by PHPSpreadsheet? Very big difference and it isn't clear from your question. If the former, files that are being downloaded by a browser, then no, you do not and can not control where the user saves them. That's completely under the control of the user.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. What I want to do briefly, is I have a table in a View in codeigniter. and I want to email it to the user. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Well it sounds like you are, or want, to use PHPSpreadsheet so use it, save the file you create, mail it then delete it. You'll want to use something like `PHPMailer` to do the mailing as it will make your life a LOT easier.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to ask. I'm saving the excel file. but it goes down to the Downloads directory under my documents. so how do I write Path in the Phpmailler commands under the Download directory?

Comment: Does saving as you describe it mean downloading it from the web browser? If so then you, from the web server perspective, can not and do not have any control over where it may be saved.